Laravel [404]: GET / - No such file or directory
i'm using laravel 8 and php 7.3
The code run fine but suddenly it show

I've tried making new laravel file but when i ctrl + f5 it's still the same
i also tried php artisan cache:clear, php artisan route:clear, php artisan config:clear, php artisan view:clear and it didn't work
i've uninstalled and installed my xampp and it didn't work
i've tried adding in apache httpd.conf, it also didn't work
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

in debug console all i get is
Launching php -dxdebug.mode=develop -S localhost:8000 -t . ...
PHP Development Server
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is "c:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\skripsiWeb"
[Mon Apr 22 18:22:03 2024] PHP 8.0.30 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
[Mon Apr 22 18:22:03 2024] [::1]:61369 Accepted
[Mon Apr 22 18:22:03 2024] [::1]:61370 Accepted
[Mon Apr 22 18:22:03 2024] [::1]:61369 [404]: GET / - No such file or directory
[Mon Apr 22 18:22:03 2024] [::1]:61369 Closing
this happens when i run artisan serve
PS C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\skripsiWeb> php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Apr 22 18:42:19 2024] PHP 8.0.30 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
Any help will be appreciated, please help!
EDIT
I use php artisan serve in the end, then open the http://127.0.0.1:8000 and it works

It lacks information. Please share your routes list and contents of public folder. It will help understand the situation.

Show the web.php
